# Right-Align Legend Feature Counts in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, legend, feature-count

I would like to align the feature counts in my legend, to look like this legend, generated in ArcGIS Online:

[image: Legend with right-justified feature counts, from ArcGIS Online]

which I believe is much easier to read than this one, generated in ArcGIS Pro:

[image: Legend with no alignment of feature counts, from ArcGIS Pro]

Is there any way in ArcGIS Pro to get the feature counts right-justified, like in the top image?

On a separate note, is anyone aware of a way to adjust the font size of the heading (in this case, "Structural Concerns") without also adjusting the size of all the other legend labels?

Answer (score 2):

An ugly solution, but this is the only way I could find so far, is to add trailing spaces in the Label symbology

**Before**:

[image]

**After**:

[image]

Comment: @Skyler, Another hack is to to manually put the count values into the description, turn that on and right justify

Answer (score 1):

This weird process randomly worked for me. I imported a map layout (lets call this map B) in ArcGIS Pro that I had previously saved in ArcMap 10.7 which was already right-justified. This legend showed up right-justified in ArcGIS Pro. I copied this right-justified legend in the ArcGIS Pro session into the other map tab I had open in ArcGIS Pro (map A) that I was trying to right-justify. Magically, it copied the legend from map A that I wanted right-justified as a right-justified legend. I have no idea why or how, but here we are.

[image: imported already right-justified legend sitting in map B]

Imported already right-justified legend sitting in map B

[image: left-justified legend that I needed to right-justify in map A, note the different scale]
Left-justified legend that I needed to right-justify in map A, note the different scale

[image: copy-pasting the legend from the other map actually pastes a right-justified map A legend]
Copy-pasting the legend from the other map actually pastes a right-justified map A legend. Note the scales are reversed, but can be manually re-labelled